# If $x_n$ is strictly decreasing and $0\le x_n<\frac{1}{2}$, then $x_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Decide following statement is true or false if it true, prove if it false give a counterexample?

If $x_n$ is strictly decreasing and $0\le x_n<\frac{1}{2}$, then $x_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $

As I think this is true statement since $inf(\{x_n\})=0$ and decreasing sequence according to the Monotone convergence theorem it is convergence to $0$

Is it correct? if it is not give a counter example?

Thank you!!

Comment: is the body or the title correct (in- or de- creasing) ?

Comment: This is wrong in increasing or decreasing case. I add counterexamples below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! Consider $x_{n} = \frac{1}{ 2^{n + 2}} + \frac{1}{4}$. This sequence is strictly decreasing and has $0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n >0$, but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} = \frac{1}{4}$.

In this case, $x_{n}\geq 0$ is not enough to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Instead, we must have $\inf x_{n} = 0$.

Comment: sorry it was typo Thank you

Comment: Isn't $0$ infimum?

Comment: No, the problem only guarantees that $x_{n}\geq 0$.

Comment: if it is $0$ is it correct?

Comment: If the infimum is $0$, then the problem statement is correct by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: how do you exactly know infimum is not $0$?

Comment: Because it is not stated in the problem, and a counterexample can be found where the infimum is not $0$. The infimum could be $0$, but it does not have to be $0$, so we cannot assume that it is $0$.

Comment: although it is not stated  it is possible to be 0

Comment: Thank you very  much. I have a doubt . I know your answer is correct but  I will solve it

Answer (score 1):

$x_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+2}$, then $x_n$ is increasing and $0 \leq x_n < \frac{1}{2} $ , but converges to $1/2$

OR

$x_n=\frac{1}{100}$+$\frac{1}{n+5}$ is strictly decreasing and $0 \leq x_n < \frac{1}{2} $, but converges to $\frac{1}{100}$

In all cases we have a counterexample.

Comment: I believe that the title is a typo, the question body says that the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: But the heading is different. Nevertheless I add the other case

Comment: Thank you it was typo